# Numpy ndarray broadcasting following a boolean condition

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I would like to know if there is a way of taking advantage of python numpy array broadcasting by avoiding to use a for loop in order to reduce computation times. Here is the following minimal example :

```
import numpy as np

# parameters
n_t = 256
G = 0.5
k_n = 10

# typical data
tau = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,256)
x_t = np.sin(tau).reshape((n_t,1))

delta = np.maximum(0,(x_t-G))
f_dot = np.zeros((n_t,1))

for i  in range(0,n_t,1):
    # boolean condition
    if delta[i,0] > 0:
        f_dot[i,0] = k_n
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in order to assign values from either `k_n` or `f_dot` according to the result of the condition:

```
f_dot = np.where(delta > 0, k_n, f_dot)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.where` is a good way to go as pointed out by @yatu. For completeness, logical masking is also an option. [In fact, there are many ways to slice an `numpy.array` object!](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

```
mask = delta>0
f_dot[mask] = k_n
```

Note this also can be reduced to one line if the mask is a throwaway: `f_dot[delta>0] = k_n`.

Comment: Thank you also for that advice, I find your answer really intuitive!